# Cómo obtener los options de una tabla

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo puedo obtener las opciones seleccionadas de una tabla que tiene selects y al mismo tiempo obtener los valores escritos por el usuario en inputs en su interior con jQuery?

Lo que deseo es generar un array y luego almacenarlo en MySQL

```
<table id="tblControlProcesoPreparacion" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;">PARAMETROS</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">ESPECIFICACIONES</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">RESULTADOS</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Olor</td>
            <td id="espec_olor"></td>
            <td><select class="selectpicker form-control">
                    <option selected hidden></option>
                    <option value="1">Cumple </option>
                    <option value="2">No Cumple</option>
                    <option value="3">No Aplica</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Apariencia</td>
            <td id="espec_apariencia"></td>
            <td><select class="selectpicker form-control">
                    <option selected hidden></option>
                    <option value="1">Cumple </option>
                    <option value="2">No Cumple</option>
                    <option value="3">No Aplica</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>PH</td>
       <td id="espec_ph"></td>
       <td><input type="number" id="in_ph" class="selectpicker form-control ph">
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la funcion `each` para el recorrido de los `tr` que existen en la tabla y obten cada uno de los valores seleccionados en los `select` despues agregalos a un arreglo

Ejemplo:

```
var array = [];
$("#tblControlProcesoPreparacion tr").each (function() {
  array.push($(this).find("td:eq(2) select option:selected").val());
});
```

le agregas un `id` a los `input select`

```
let olor=$("#espec_olor select option:selected").val();
let apariencia=$("#espec_apariencia select option:selected").val();
let in_ph=$("#in_ph").val();
array.push({"olor":olor,"apariencia":apariencia,"in_ph":in_ph});
```

Comment: Super. Muchas gracias, estoy haciendo una variacion al formulario y es que ademas de tener selects tambien tenga inputs, ¿como podria adicionarlo al codigo que tienes? modifique el codigo inicial

Comment: puedes acceder directo a los input solo asignandoles un id,